Celery chord with tasks that have a celery group
I have a complicated system that uses a lot of async processing, and I'm trying to make it work a little better. Initially, there is a celery chord that calls the same task with different data about 7k times, and then sends the results to a callback.
The task it calls then has a celery group of 4 separate tasks. Originally these 4 tasks were run with a threadpool, but I'm interested in getting them into a celery group for a bunch of reasons (rate limiting being one of them). My current approach is to make the group blocking, with:
def some_function(**kwargs):
    results = group(task1.s(**kwargs),
                    task2.s(**kwargs),
                    task3.s(**kwargs),
                    task4.s(**kwargs))
    res1, res2, res3, res4 = results.apply_async().get()
    return res1, res2, res3, res4

However, that's.. not great. Especially since celery specifically says:
RuntimeError: Never call result.get() within a task!
See https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#avoid-launching-synchronous-subtasks

I'd love to find some way to send the results of this to a callback that basically collects the results and sends them back to the chord to collect and send to the original callback. I'm not sure if that exists yet though, and I can figure out another solution, like storing in redis in the meantime, but was hoping to find a celery canvas solution.
Basically, this:

Chord of 7k tasks go out to workers
Each task calls 4 tasks in a group
Results of step 2 finish and are sent to a callback that sends it to the chord in step 1 (rather than returning directly)

Does this make sense? Anyone know a good solution? Thanks in advance!
